# tableView(tableView, viewFor:,: Int) strange behavior

Tags: macos, swift5

I'm trying to craft a view based tableView delegate method to alter a column's font IFF its identifier is 'name' and its value matches some global; otherwise the the nib should prevail. I think I have either a noob setup issue or my logic is omitting something.

I have two tables, one view based (tag=0), one cell (tag=1), and both have the same view controller as their delegate. Each tableView's has a unique tag and identifier, an array controller for column value bindings, and each of fits columns has an explicit unique identifier - matching its binding; I had tried omitting this - "the automatic setting" - but this yielded no data!?

So, I added this method, but both tableViews call into it; I would expect only the first.  The 2nd table is a detail of the 1st, having its 1st array controller selection.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let item = ((tableView.dataSource as! NSArrayController).arrangedObjects as! [AnyObject])[row]
    var view = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self)
    if view ==  nil {
        Swift.print("tag: \(tableView.tag) ident: \(tableColumn!.identifier.rawValue)")
        view = NSTableCellView.init()
        view?.identifier = tableColumn?.identifier
    }

    guard tableView.tag == 0 else { return view }

    guard isGlobalPlist, item.name == '<some-global-string>',
        let identifier = tableColumn?.identifier,
        identifier.rawValue == "name" else { return view }

    if let cellView = view as? NSTableCellView {
        if tableView.selectedRowIndexes.intersection(IndexSet.init(integer: row)).count > 0 {
            cellView.textField?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: -1)
            cellView.textField?.textColor = .white
        }
        else
        {
            cellView.textField?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: -1)
            cellView.textField?.textColor = .blue
        }
    }
    return view
}
```

Firstly I notice that the method is called for the 2nd table when I wouldn't have expect it, it being a cell based tableView.

Anyway, I do create the cell when nil return, the docs cite that you need just need to matchup the identifiers:

`Note that a cell view’s identifier must be the same as its table column’s identifier for bindings to work. If you’re using bindings, it’s recommended that you use the Automatic identifier setting in Interface Builder.`

which I do; both tableView's columns are bound (view, or cell) to their respective array controller using column identifier explicitly entered.

Anyway the original intent I was after was for the view based (1st) tableView:

- the view controller was controlling a global resource (isGlobalPlist is true)
- the row's 'name' value matches a global value value

to the affect 'name' cell shown in distinct color (blue/yellow - or something) depending on whether the row was selected due to selection highlighting, dark mode etc conditions.

So there would be 1 of 4 possibilities

1. selected row,         matching global -> fore:yellow,  back:default
2. selected row,     not matching global -> fore:default, back:default
3. non-selected row,     matching global -> fore:blue,    back:default
4. non-selected row, not matching global -> fore:default, back:default

If the target row matched requirements, the coloring needs to vary depending on its inclusion in the tableView's selected indexes.

The setting seems to properly affect initially - selected row and matching value, but then settings seem to bleed across other rows navigated to - so the selection change. At most there should be 1 row's name column with this affect.

I can't tell if my logic or setup is wrong; I suspect I probably need to refresh as I move about ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I gave up on a view based solution but this fills my need; a cell based solution:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, dataCellFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSCell? {
    guard let column = tableColumn else { return nil }

    let item : AnyObject = ([table0ArrayController,table1ArrayController][tableView.tag]?.arrangedObjects as! [AnyObject])[row]
    let cell : NSTextFieldCell = column.dataCell(forRow: row) as! NSTextFieldCell
    cell.textColor = .textColor

    guard tableView.tag == 0, isGlobalPlist, item.name == '<some-global-string>' else { return cell }

    if tableView.selectedRowIndexes.intersection(IndexSet.init(integer: row)).count > 0 {
        cell.textColor = .white
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textColor = .blue
    }

    return cell
}
```

I wanted to call attention to specific row(s) with color, unless row was selected for the 'name' column only.